# Inflection point not found for the function $f(x) = 2\arctan(x) - \dfrac{x^3}{x^2+1}$. Should it?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

$f'(x) = -\dfrac{x^4+x^2-2}{\left(x^2+1\right)^2} = \dfrac{(x+1)(x-1)(-x^2-2)}{\left(x^2+1\right)^2}$

This gives the critical points $x=-1 \quad\&\quad x=1$.

Solving those with sign analysis; one finds two local extreme values at $x=-1\quad \&\quad x=1$. However, just watching the [plot of the derivative](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot%20-%28%28-2%20%2B%20x%5E2%20%2B%20x%5E4%29%2F%281%20%2B%20x%5E2%29%5E2%29) makes me suspicious.

I know that for an inflection point, the condition $f''(x) = 0$ is **necessary** but not **sufficient**, *am I right here?*

So sure, I can't draw the conclusion from just that plot. However, looking at the [plot of the original function](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot%202*tan%5E%28-1%29%28x%29-x%5E3%2F%28x%5E2%2B1%29) it actually **does** look like the **derivative** $f'(x)$ does change signs at $x=0$.

Am I in the complete wrong here? Should I trust my algebra or have I done it wrong?

Comment: There's no need to close the question. If you know the answer to it, please feel free to post an answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to my computation, we have
$$
f''(x)=-\frac{2x(x^2+5)}{(x^2+1)^3}
$$
which shows $f$ has an inflection point at $0$.

An inflection point is a point where a function changes from concave to convex or conversely. If $f$ is a twice differentiable function, a necessary (but not sufficient) condition for $x$ to be an inflection point is that $f''(x)=0$. But if the second derivative has different signs at either side of $x$ and $f''(x)=0$, the point $x$ is an inflection point.

The sign change of a function has nothing to do with inflection points.

Note that this function ***must*** have an inflection point between $-1$ and $1$, because it's convex in a neighborhood of $-1$ and concave in a neighborhood of $1$ and it is infinitely differentiable. Moreover it is odd, so its second derivative is odd, too, so $f''(x)=0$.

Comment: Bravo! I deleted my answer. I felt so secure about my answer; thank you for saving me from my own ignorance.

Comment: How does one reach the conclusion that $x=0$ is an interesting point though? Besides looking at computer plotted graphs?

Comment: @XMLParsing The function you're dealing with is odd: $f(-x)=-f(x)$, so of course $0$ is interesting, because it's a center of symmetry for the function's graph.